# WordPress 3.2 JavaScript errors after upgrade

Tags: javascript, wordpress

all

After successful upgrade to WordPress some JavaScript reporting errors. I can't add tags to post, and edit permalink.

Safari is reporting this errors:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'g.prop("disabled")') post.php:500
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'editPermalink(1196)') load-scripts.php:41
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'jQuery(":button, :submit","#submitpost").prop("disabled",true)')
```

With Chrome is simplier:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'prop' load-scripts.php:219
```

I tried to Google this erros, but without any success. Upgrade was automatic, but after failure I manualy replaces whole wp-admin and wp-includes directories, and disabled all existing plugins. Any ideas what else I can do? Without downgrading to previous version?

Comment: Have you tried [the Wordpress forums](http://wordpress.org/support/forum/installation)?

Comment: Have you ensured jQuery or some other dependency updated. I'd like to think WP Core wouldn't miss such things.

Comment: I'd upload load-scripts.php manually via ftp incase it got corrupted, or not updated.

Answer (score 1):

WP3.2 went to jQuery 1.6.1, so you probably have a plugin or old theme conflict. Deactivate all plugins, switch to twentyten and see what happens.

WP3.2 also requires PHP version 5.2.4 or greater and MySQL version 5.0.15 or greater